# Can anyone recommend me some book on semitic linguistics?

Tags: semitic-languages

Anything that is for beginners would be appreciated. Something that introduces the subject to someone who is completely new

Comment: beginner at what? semitic languages? linguistics? comparative linguistics?  what specifically is your goal?

Comment: sorry i want on comparative ling.

Comment: sorry I don't have a specific recommendation.  but do look into historical linguistics, the fields are closely related. von Humboldt is the classic reference.  for a brilliant modern exposition see "After Herder" https://books.google.com/books/about/After_Herder.html?id=MtCquQAACAAJ

Answer (score 2):

Introduction to the Semitic Languages (Gotthelf Bergstrasser), [Comparative Grammar of the Semitic Languages](http://www.semiticroots.net/downloads/Comparative%20Grammar%20of%20the%20Semitic%20Languages.pdf), Comparative Semitic Linguistics (Patrick Bennett). The last of these is probably best, as an introduction.